# How to use date picker with objective c

Tags: cocoa

I am developing app for storing employee details using objective c and core data. I want to use the date picker for storing joining date of employees. Please let me know the code base for using date picker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't quite need a codebase... Just create one in Interface Builder and connect it to an outlet of your viewcontroller. Then just ask it for its date property, which is of type [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you'd like to set the shown date just create a NSDate (or read it from another source) and assign it to the date pickers date property.

If you'd like to run code when the date has been changed by the user, you need an IBAction method as well which will be called whenever the date has been changed and thus gives you the opportunity to do something with the new date.

Your outlet could look like this:

```
//in your viewcontrollers .h file
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *myDatePicker;
```

Then read a date like this:

```
//in your viewcontrollers .h file
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged: (id)sender;

//in your viewcontrollers .m file
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged: (id)sender {
   NSDate *selectedDate = [sender date];
   //do something with selectedDate
}
```

You don't necessarily need the outlet by the way, if reading the date once it has been changed is sufficient, because a reference to the datepicker will be sent along (sender).

**Edit:**

To answer the Core Data part of your question, I suggest reading the Core Data Programming Guide if you're new to Core Data. This is a very complex technology and hard to explain here. What you ultimately need to do however is creating a core data entity which offers an attribute of type "date". Once you create a new instance of this entity, you can just set this attribute to the date property read from your datepicker.